# RSpec sequence error: undefined method `primary_key' for String:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

This is my `spec/factories/nodes.rb`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :node do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Node#{n}" }
    family_tree nil
    user nil
    media ""
  end
end
```

This is my `node_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Node do
  it "is valid with a name" do
    # node = Node.new(generate(:name))
    expect(build(:node)).to be_valid
  end
end
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Failures:

  1) Node is valid with a name
     Failure/Error: expect(build(:node)).to be_valid
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `primary_key' for String:Class
```

This is the schema for my `Node.rb` model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: nodes
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  name           :string(255)
#  family_tree_id :integer
#  user_id        :integer
#  media_id       :integer
#  media_type     :string(255)
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
#  circa          :datetime
#  is_comment     :boolean

  validates :name, presence: true
```

Thoughts?

**Edit 1**

So I just deleted the entire file, and replaced it with this and it works now:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :node do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Node#{n}"  }
  end
end
```

I don't know what worked though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the previous `FactoryGirl` definition which assigned the empty string to the `media` field of a `Node`. You haven't shared your definition of the `Node` class, but presumably `media` is an `ActiveRecord` association. This in turn would need to get the primary key value from any object assigned to `media` so that it can set the `media_id` field in the record.